# How to send data as an object through .post() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I make a .post() request such as

```
var data = $(this).serialize();
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('server.php', data, function(data) {
        $('#data').append('<p>' + data + '</p>');
    });
});
```

everything's working - the name from the database appends to the #data element withing the p tags. But, when I try to pass data as an object like this

```
var data = $(this).serialize();
$.post('server.php', {id: data}, function(data) {
    $('#data').append('<p>' + data + '</p>');
});
```

than it doesn't work. I tried changing the argument of the function within the .post() to id and probably every combination of names for .post()'s arguments and variables within the PHP file also, without success. Here's the working intact PHP file compatible with the first version of my .post() request in this question:

```
<?php

    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dummy_db');

    $query = 'SELECT name FROM dummy_db_table WHERE id = "' . $id . '"';
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    echo $row["name"];

    $connection->close();

?>
```

Please note that the name of the input field for the ID in the HTML file is 'id'. I do understand that it is this name attribute within HTML which helps PHP determine the value of it, but how is it doing so without me specifying the connection with the PHP through form's action attribute? I'm doing this exclusively through AJAX (.post()) and AJAX is not telling PHP anything specific about THAT id field. What am I missing here? Also, how would I go about sending the object of values instead of a single one through .post()'s data attribute? Thank you.

Comment: what is the problem with the first version? what are you trying to achieve by using 2nd version

Comment: I'm trying to pass a second data value in order to update a MySQL table (no update statement is shown in the given code example, but it is there). So one data value is the ID and the other is, say, the time when employee logged in for work. In order to update a log in time for that specific employee I need his ID. That second value, log in time, will be updated for him based on his ID.

Comment: `serialize` will get you a string of `name=value` pairs for your form fields, separated by an ampersand – standard query string formatting. Now by encapsulating this into another object using `{id: data}`, you will end up with an `id` parameter that has a value such as `foo=123`. Does it make any sense inserting that into your SQL query, where it will end up as something like `… WHERE id = "foo=123"` …? No, of course it doesn’t.

Comment: that can be done by the first version itself what is the problem with that...

Answer (score 0):

You have not add the form code here so lets assume your form have two fields name and address. 
Actually you need to put the serialize() function under the event. Like

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('server.php', {id: data}, function(data) {
        $('#data').append('<p>' + data + '</p>');
    });
});
```

Now on your server.php file if you print the following line:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
```

this will show you the results like: **name=iffi&address=UK**

I hope this will help you more.